# Drupal 7 - assign several products (items) under each category

Tags: drupal-7

In D7, I have created a taxonomy (say categories) and set some terms (say category 1, category 2 etc) within it. I have also created a 'View' based on the 'categories' taxonomy and show the categories (category 1, category 2 etc) within the sidebar (block) of the website. Just let me know how can I assign several products (items) under each category so that site visitors can see the product lists on clicking a category from the sidebar. Basically I want to develop a catalogue based website to show products/items under each category.

Kindly help me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning,

If you have not done yet, you have to create a custom content type (Structure > Content Types > Add content type) and add as many fields as you need. When you are done, you have to **add an extra field** named Category, of type "Taxonomy Term Reference" (or something similar, I don't know exactly). You can configure this field so that you can assign several categories to a single product.

Once your contents are created, if you access the taxonomy term's URL, all contents assigned to that category should be displayed. However, you could also define a custom view that receives the name of the category as a parameter in the URL, and displays all contents in this category in a grid, table, list, ... whatever.

Hope it helps.